# AsyncTask Save Variables from doInBackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have two `AsyncTasks` as inner classes in my `Activity`. One returns an `ArrayList` in `doInBackground` and asigns a `ListAdapter` to it on `postExecute`. The other `AsyncTask` returns a `StringArray` and sets some `TextViews`.

On Rotation everything is gone, also the layout changes on Rotation.

I'd like to have access to the results of the `doInBackground`-Methods. If I had access I could just simply save the variables in `onSaveInstanceState` and reasign the values manually.

Comment: Have you considered separating the `AsyncTask` management into a `Service` and just talking to the `Service` from the `Activity`?

Comment: Not at all. I haven't looked into services and I rather stay with my working code and fix it instead of changing the whole setup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the results of `doInBackground` in `onPostExecute`.

Simply change your class to:

```
public class YourTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ObjectYouWantToReturn> {

    @Override
    protected ObjectYouWantToReturn doInBackground(Beneficiary... params) {        
        ObjectYouWantToReturn obj = new ObjectYouWantToReturn();
        //... do your stuff
        return obj;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ObjectYouWantToReturn result) {
        //there you go, here you have the results from doInBackground
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shared preferences is solution of your problem i think.

revise the link given below.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

http://thedevelopersinfo.com/2009/11/25/getting-sharedpreferences-from-other-application-in-android/